# Getting ListData from a SharePoint list and then binding the results to a dropdown field, but how can I remove duplicates?

Tags: rest, sharepoint, knockout.js

I have got list data from a SharePoint list and have binded one column of data into a dropdown using knockoutJS. I am now trying to remove duplicates from the binded results, but am struggling.

**Here's my code so far:**

```
var Info = ko.observable();
var AppModel = {
                    Acts: ko.observableArray([]),
                    sel: ko.observable()
}


$(function () {
    $.ajax({
            dataType: "json",
            url: "MYLIST/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/LISTNAME?$select=Title",
            data: {},
            success: dataCallBack
    });
    ko.applyBindings();
});


function dataCallBack(data) {
    var newData = [];
    for(var idx=0; idx < data.d.results.length; idx++) {

            function dataCallBack(data) {

                var newData = [];
                for(var idx=0; idx < data.d.results.length; idx++) {

                    var e = data.d.results[idx];

            var foundItem = return ko.utils.arrayFirst(newData, function(item) {
                return item == e;
            });

            if (!foundItem){
                newData.push(e);
            }
                }

                AppModel.Acts(newData);

}
```

**HTML Here**

```
<select id="location-input" data-bind="options: AppModel.Acts,
                        optionsText: 'Title
                        optionsCaption: 'Choose...',
                            value: AppModel.sel">
</select>
```

Can anyone advise as to where I'm going wrong? I think the for loop is breaking at the if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your attempt for checking duplicates is wrong.

Try something like this:

```
var foundItem = ko.utils.arrayFirst(newData, function(item) {
    return item == e;
});

if (!foundItem)
{
    newData.push(e);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I have updated my code above with your suggestion but the dropdown isn't being populated with the results.

Comment: It works! Just had to add .Title to each item property and remove 'return' from start of ko.utils...